# TFS source control of SSIS projects in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis, bids, team-explorer

Consider these 2 machines:

- ## 1: Full SQL Server 2008 without Team Explorer (test SQL box)
- ## 2: Development box with Visual Studio 2008 SP1 with Team Explorer

I use Team Foundation Server 2008 and would like to check SSIS projects into source control. Do I need to install BIDS as a separate Visual Studio 2008 shell in my machine #2? I would prefer to use the existing Visual Studio, as it already works ok with TFS via Team Explorer. What do I need to install to achieve this?

Instead, should I install Team Explorer in machine #1 to be able to check in to source control?

Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to my previous setup.

Since BIDS actually uses DevEnv.exe in the background, all you need is the project type installed, and everything else flows (TFS or VSS and any other Visual Studio add ons).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when you install BIDS on a machine with VS, it will use the existing settings, so my team explorer showed up correctly.
I also needed to install Business Intelligence in my development box.